# function prototype call another function prototype javascript

Tags: javascript, function-prototypes

```
function Chat() {
    // hander vent //
    // this.message_text.on("keyup click", this.saveMessage);
    $('.chat').on("click", this.init);
}

Chat.prototype.init = function() {
    var sef = this;
    this.hihi();
}
Chat.prototype.hihi = function() {
    return 2;
}

let chat = new Chat();
```

I have two methods define in class type prototype.
but when I call function name hihi inside function init.
when I run code single with create instance with type Chat.
it can't run and show error.

> TypeError: this.hihi is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.Chat.init (fotozidiqo.js:9:10)

How I can call this function in init function name.

Comment: `this.init.bind(this)`

Answer (score -1):

When doing this: `$('.chat').on("click", this.init);`, jQuery changes the `this` of the `init()` method to the element returned from `$('.chat')`. That's why it's undefined when you call `this.hihi();` within the init method, because it doesn't exists on `HTMLElement`.

So in order to get the proper `this` you have to bind the `this` of the `Chat` prototype like so:

```
function Chat() {
    $('.chat').on("click", this.init.bind(this));
}
```

> If you want to debug this, you can `console.log(this)` on your `init()` method and you'll see a `HTMLElement`.

Comment: It's not a scope issue. `this` is not called "scope".

Comment: can you suggest me correct solution

Comment: @tomnyson changing this, `$('.chat').on("click", this.init.bind(this));` should do the job.